# Looking for problem sets suitable to go with Physics from Symmetry

Tags: homework-and-exercises, symmetry, resource-recommendations, group-theory, education

I'm reading through Physics from Symmetry by Jakob Schwitenberg - which is fantastic so far. I'm a math/physics undergrad on my last semester of lower division and this is a refreshing take on physics. That being said, while nearly everything about this book is perfect it lacks problem sets at the end of sections. Are there any problem sets that fit nicely with this book?

Alternatively, are there mathematical physics books that start with the idea of linear transformations and slowly build up groups and lie algebras in an intuitive way, like Schwitenberg, that also include problem sets?

Comment: I hope you read the second edition, cause the first one is a disaster.

Comment: Lol, I read the reviews of both editions and went with the second edition, since that seemed to be the consensus of most people.